# What are some practical uses of Generalized Algebraic Datatypes?

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming, haskell, type-systems, ocaml

All tutorials on GADTs that I've seen (in Haskell, Coq and Idris) use one same exapmle of a well-typed interpreter to show how GADTs can be useful, where you use the type index to encode the type of the term in the object language.

What are some other examples and general rules for when we should think of GADT as a solution?

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: admins why do you ruin your own community??  Good question, let him ask!

Answer (score -5):

Link dump for the OCaml side of things:

- [Detecting use-cases for GADTs in OCaml](http://mads-hartmann.com/ocaml/2015/01/05/gadt-ocaml.html)
- [Explain me GADTs like i'm 5](https://dd.reddit.com/r/ocaml/comments/1jmjwf/explain_me_gadts_like_im_5_or_like_im_an/)

Some concrete use cases:

- [Why GADTs matter for performance](https://blogs.janestreet.com/why-gadts-matter-for-performance/)
- [Diff lists and Format](http://drup.github.io/2016/08/02/difflists/)
- The list of [github repositories tagged "gadt"](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Agadt&type=Repositories).
- Very incomplete list of OCaml libraries with reasonably advanced uses:

  - The [Bigarray module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.html) and the Format module (see post about difflists) in the stdlib.
  - [Index-aware linear algebra](http://akabe.github.io/slap/)
  - Core, probably a bit everywhere.
  - [Heterogeneous maps](https://github.com/dbuenzli/hmap)
  - [The mirage DSL](https://github.com/mirage/functoria)
  - [Typesafe routing](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocplib-resto)

Comment: Link dumps don't make good answers because links eventually die.  Can you bring some of the relevant content from these links into your answer?

Comment: No I can't. OP expects a set of concrete use cases, So I provide concrete use cases as links to the actual libraries. Not a simplified toy explanation that would fit here. This is an extremely common question that comes back frequently. I don't see the value of not pointing to external significant sources.

Comment: @Drup It's against the conventions of this site. Note that the question itself is off-topic here and shouldn't be answered at all.